# how to add hidden fields in Facebook Registration Plugin?

Tags: php, facebook

i am using facebook registration to send some data to a post.php file:

```
<?php
$fields = json_encode(array(
array('name' => 'first_name'),
array('name' => 'last_name'),
    array('name' => 'phone', 'description' => 'Phone Number', 'type' => 'text')
));

?>
<iframe class="facebook-login" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&
         redirect_uri=http://www.xxx.com/poet.php&
         fields=<?php echo urlencode($fields);?>"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

But i want to send also a hidden field with some data inside it, something like:

```
array('name' => 'hidden', 'description' => '', 'type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>'123456')
```

but this wont return the `123456` value

any ideas?

thanks

edit:

if facebook doesn't allow hidden fields how to a pass a var to `http://www.xxx.com/poet.php`..

i am decoding the message like this:

```
$response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], FACEBOOK_SECRET);
$fname = $response['registration']['first_name'];
```

Comment: Please check the source code of your login page, if the hidden field does exist in the generated form. Might be, that facebook does not allow hidden fields for security reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why *would* facebook allow hidden fields? The data in the form is sourced either from Facebook or from user input. If you want to maintain a value through to the next script, use a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variable.

Comment: I would say, facebook *could* allow hidden fields by the same reason that vanilla html forms support them - they are simply more convenient than session vars in many cases...

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Facebook does allow hidden variables. It is stated very explicitly in the docs. There are actually three ways to pass a value:
1.) Define a field with type "hidden" and deafult the value
2.) Assign a value manually to the session cookie (requires XFBML)
3.) Pass a variable manually via the request uri

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **default** attribute.

{'name' => 'language', 'description' => 'Language', 'type' => 'hidden', **'default'** => I18n.locale}

Answer (score 0):

Facebook registration allows hidden fields:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

> Supported values are text, date, select, checkbox, typeahead, and **hidden**.

See the Custom Fields section on the details to do this.

Comment: The facebook hidden fields is for fetching data from facebook without showing it on the form - it's not for prefilling and passing data through. For example, if you wanted to collect `birthday` without showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like facebook doesn't support pass-through hidden variables, but you should be able to emulate them by adding `?hidden=value` to your redirect_uri.

Answer (score 0):

Mr mrhaddad is very close.... correct syntax is:

```
$fields = "[{'name':'name'}, 
{'name':'email'},
{'name':'City','description':'City','type':'text'},
{'name':'State','description':'State','type':'text'},
{'name':'ZipCode','description':'Zip Code','type':'text'},
{'name':'Telephone','description':'Your Best Telephone Number','type':'text'},
{'name':'thisUserID','description':'thisUserID','type':'hidden','default':'".$user_id."'}
]";
```

To capture FB user info.... use the FB id returned in the signed request and make another request to the FB open graph.